# generalization of Cauchy-Riemann conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Esteemed experts,

Please excuse the ignorance and language of a poor physicist.

1. As we know, the real $u(x,y)$ and imaginary $v(x,y)$ parts of an analytic function (in some domain) satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann (CR) conditions

   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$

   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}.$
2. In contrast, in the problem that I encountered, I am looking at the following equations

   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \sigma(x,y)\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$

   $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\sigma(x,y)\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x},$

   where $\sigma(x,y)$ is a sufficiently smooth function. The latter equations look like  the CR conditions but are not equivalent to them because $\sigma(x,y)$ depends on $(x,y)$.
3. My question is whether it is possible to generalize the complex analysis to have the generalized Cauchy-Riemann conditions with position-dependent $\sigma(x,y)$. Perhaps someone can point me to the relevant references.

Thanks in advance,
Serge

Comment: Random observation: if $\sigma(x,y)=e^{2\varphi(x,y)}$ then setting $\hat u=e^{-\varphi(x,y)}u$ and $\hat v=e^{\varphi(x,y)}v$ yields $$ \frac{\partial\hat u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial\hat v}{\partial y} = - \nabla\varphi \cdot (\hat u,\hat v) \qquad\qquad \frac{\partial\hat u}{\partial y} + \frac{\partial\hat v}{\partial x} = \nabla\varphi\cdot(\hat v,-\hat u)$$

Comment: ... or, with a bit of free-wheeling abuse of notation, $$\begin{pmatrix}\partial_x & -\partial_y \\ \partial_y & \partial_x\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\hat u \\ \hat v\end{pmatrix} = -\begin{pmatrix}\hat u & \hat v \\ -\hat v & \hat u \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \partial_x \\ \partial_y \end{pmatrix} \varphi $$ which if nothing else looks intriguingly symmetric _in form_.

Comment: Thank you! This is a helpful observation! In other words, the new functions that you introduced satisfy the inhomogenous Cauchy-Riemann conditions $\partial_x \hat u - \partial_y \hat v = \alpha(x,y)$ and $\partial_y \hat u + \partial_x \hat v = \beta(x,y)$. This pair of equations may be written as $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z} = \gamma(z,\bar z)$. I will try to think along these lines...

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That sounds like it would be deserving of an answer that explains the "bit of trickery" you're speaking of.

Answer (score 1):

The equation that you have is a special case of the more general class of **quasilinear** differential equations in the complex plane studied by Bojarskii (and others); the English translation of his paper can be found [here](http://www.math.jyu.fi/research/reports/rep118.pdf),

*Bojarski, B. V.*, Generalized solutions of a system of differential equations of the first order and elliptic type with discontinuous coefficients. Translated from the 1957 Russian original. With a foreword by Eero Saksman, Report. University of Jyväskylä. Department of Mathematics and Statistics 118. Jyväskylä: University of Jyväskylä, Department of Mathematics and Statistics (ISBN 978-951-39-3486-6/pbk). 64 p. (2009). [ZBL1173.35403](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1173.35403).

In the context of your problem, Bojarski  considers a measurable (more precisely, $L_\infty$) function $\sigma$ of two variables in an (open, connected and bounded) domain $D$ in the complex plane. He proves the existence of solution (section 2 of the paper) and much more (including a form of uniqueness, see section 6 of his paper). Solutions in his case are understood in the sense of distributions (he would allow discontinuous functions $\sigma$) under the very mild assumption that $|\sigma|$ is bounded away from zero in $D$. Since you probably do not know what distributions are, just assume continuity of $\sigma$. If and when you try to read his paper, simply replace "measurable" with "continuous" and then you can work with classical (instead of distributional) derivatives.

The solutions of this equation are generalizations of holomorphic functions (sometimes called "quasiregular") and share many of their properties. For instance, "generically" the solution is a local **quasiconformal** homeomorphism. In general, solutions can be described as compositions $h\circ f$, where $h$ is a holomorphic function and $f$ is a quasiconformal homeomorphism.

The case when $\sigma$ is allowed to approach zero were also subsequently studied, see for instance

*Sevost’yanov, E. A.*, [**On quasilinear Beltrami-type equations with degeneration**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1134/S0001434611090112), Math. Notes 90, No. 3, 431-438 (2011); translation from Math. Zametki 90, No. 3, 445-453 (2011). [ZBL1291.30140](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1291.30140).

The nature of solutions in this case is much less clear (at least to me).

Edit. Here is some background on [quasiconformal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconformal_mapping).

Comment: Curious to know what class of functions are there for simpler $ y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}, x\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$..